# unable to save or cancel subscriptions using Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, subscriptions

Using stripe's API with Ruby on Rails I am unable to save subscriptions.

I am able to retrieve and update and save customer objects:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(some_customer_id) #this works
customer.save #this works
```

I am also able to retrieve subscriptions:
subscription=customer.subscriptions.retrieve("some_subscription_id") #this works

However, when trying to save a subscription:
subscription.save #this doesn't work

I keep getting this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for 
#<Stripe::StripeObject:0x007ff37147c720>
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/stripe-    
1.9.9/lib/stripe/stripe_object.rb:158:in `method_missing'
```

Similarly when trying to cancel a subscription:

```
customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_3QM09lOz64QuSf").delete()
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for 
    #<Stripe::StripeObject:0x007ff36d3f0d50>
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/stripe-
    1.9.9/lib/stripe/stripe_object.rb:158:in `method_missing'
```

Without this I am not able to allow customers to cancel directly from the site.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok using gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby' instead of just gem 'stripe' seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade to their latest gem with `bundle update stripe` and try again. Subscriptions were changed sometime around 1.10.0 and requires a version after that to save them.  By configuring your gemfile to use their github repository you're essentially using the latest version available at the time of your bundle.