# Stripe upgrade subscription - plan change

Tags: php, symfony, payment, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a recurring payment by using Stripe. It works just fine, but the problem is that I have 4 different payment plans, and the first time the user is paying, I am subscribing him to the lowest plan. Then, if I try to change the subscription, and set it to another plan, just like in their official documentation, it does not work for me. The code from their documentation looks like this:

```
 Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_cTYCUNuIv8w6NeJcXSoAeLDO"); 
 $cu = Stripe_Customer::retrieve("cus_4keRPGExpTWMwe"); 
 $subscription = $cu->subscriptions->retrieve("sub_4keRoLrCJiHzAq"); 
 $subscription->plan = "gold"; 
 $subscription->save();
```

If I try to save the subscription, it gives me an error which says that the save method is not defined.
Do you know any workarounds?

Thank you.

Comment: are you passing in the correct customer & subscription id's?

Comment: Yes, and the subscription object that I want to change is a Stripe_Object, and I took a look in vendor, and examined this class, and it doesn't have the save() method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to save or cancel subscriptions using Stripe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517728/unable-to-save-or-cancel-subscriptions-using-stripe)

Comment: @user3906380 Did this ever get solved because I am seeing the same issue?

Comment: yes, I've managed to fix the problem by making first an api call to Stripe and retrieve the plan object, then done something like this "$subscription->plan = $StripePlan;"

Comment: Another option for changing plans looks like this:
$cu->updateSubscription(["plan" => "new_plan_id"]);
$cu->save();